# 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows-xp, apache-http-server, maven

I get the following error when i type the command `mvn --version`

'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890116/apache-maven-install-mvn-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-a) but still i am unable to get the work done.

when i type this command `echo %M2_HOME%` i get path printed as `D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4`

when i type 'echo %M2%' i get the path printed as `D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin`

Environment : `Windows XP`

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: and how about `echo %PATH%`

Comment: it got me the following `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;%PROGRAMFILES%\Internet Explorer;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;%M2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append maven bin directory path to Windows %PATH% variable.

`Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables` -> The path variable is in the second section the `*System variables*`.

Ensure you have the value `;%M2_HOME%\bin;` (note the semi-colon, different paths should be separated by them) in order for Windows to be able to find the Maven command definitions.

```
Ensure you restart your command prompt. Environment variables need to be set before you open your command prompt.
```